# how to get different element by class

Tags: visual-studio, appium, screen-scraping

I'm working on data scrapping project. where i have to scrape the data from roaster. But the problem i'm getting is there is one grid view and it contain four different fields horizontally. and infinite fields vertically. But the problem is i'm getting same class name . how can i differentiate between all. [image]

Comment: please show your code and the html source

Comment: You read the rows into an array.  Trouble is, you can only read the number of rows that are on the screen at any given time, so you're going to need to read as many rows as are visible, then scroll and read again until the scroll has reached the end.  By the way, it's roster not roaster, and it's not an infinite number of rows, just undetermined or unknown.